# Disable HDMI CEC in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

I always connected my laptop directly to my screen via HDMI. Everything worked 100% for more than a year.

Last week I connected my laptop to a Denon amp (AVR) and the amp is connected to my screen. Since then, strange things started happening. For instance: my screen randomly goes black for a couple of seconds about 20 times a day. Sometimes my computer even randomly goes into standby mode or even shuts down.

This only happens when I connect to my screen through the amp. The only explanation I have is that my amp somehow sends HDMI CEC signals to my laptop and that's why it is happening.

Does anyone know how to turn off CEC in Windows 7? I'm running a 64bit operating system and have a GeForce 560M (my drivers are up-to-date).